# hover-menu in right side of fixed div

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, css-position

I have a div with a fixed position (a top panel) which shall also contain a settings menu at the far right (currently via floating).

When hovering over the settings-image, I want to display a menu below the image.
I want the menu to be aligned to the right side just like the image.

```
<div id="panel" style="position:fixed">
  <panel-entry 1>
  <panel-entry 2>
  <panel-entry n>

  <div id="settings" style="float:right/snapped to the right side>
    <img src=settings>
    <ul>
      <li>setting 1</li>
      <li>setting 2</li>
      <li>setting n</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea using jQuery very much appreciated, feel free to rearrange any html.

Comment: Have a look at jQuery menu plugin http://jqueryui.com/menu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No jQuery necessary, just give your `#panel` a width:

```
#panel {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
#settings {
  float: right;
}
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uVp45/6/).

Answer (score 1):

Aside from your example **not being HTML**, I would anyhow correct the conceptual approach. There is no jQuery required for such a task, which can be done entirely in CSS.

1. You want your `#panel` to first of all contain a `<ul>` which will contain `<li>`s, which will be your `<panel-entry>`, those should be set as `inline-block`.
2. The `#settings` should be one of those, perhaps with a special `class` or `id` (we'll keep settings for now). You can `position: absolute` this to `right: 0`, or have it `float`. Don't use an image element for this, but rather use a `background-image`.
3. Inside this element, you will have a submenu: i.e. another `<ul>` with `display: none`, a `position:absolute`, `right: 0` and `top: X`, so that X doesn't overlap with your `#panel`.
4. Next, you want to make the element visible on `:hover` of `li#settings`.

<kbd>[**Here's a working demo**](http://jsbin.com/uwagoh/3)</kbd>

### Basic HTML

```
<div id="panel">
  <ul>
      <li>Panel entry 1</li>
      <li>Panel entry 2</li>
      <li>Panel entry n</li>
      <li id="settings">

        <ul>
          <li>setting 1</li>
          <li>setting 2</li>
          <li>setting n</li>
        </ul>

      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

### Basic CSS

```
#panel {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#panel > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#panel > ul > li > ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: {X};
  right: 0;
}

li#settings {

  background: url({youricon}) no-repeat top center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  min-width: {youricon-x};
  min-height: {youricon-y};
}

li#settings:hover > ul{

  display: block;

}
```