# how to redirect a url with pk to url with pk and slug in django?

Tags: django, django-urls, http-redirect

when a user enters this url below

```
www.example.com/1234
```

he must be redirected to

```
www.example.com/1234/this-is-your-first-post
```

For example, if you try this:

```
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15443306/
```

you will be redirected to

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15443306/hover-menu-in-right-side-of-fixed-div
```

Actually it is not a `redirect`, it is just extending the `url` with `slug field`automatically.

I want to implement this feature:
Here is my models

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    body = models.TextField()
    # image = models.ImageField(upload_to="/", blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField()
    likes = models.IntegerField()
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article_detail', kwargs={'slug':self.slug, 'pk':self.id})

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Here is my `urls.py` inside my app

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'all$', ArticleList.as_view(), name='blog_all'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w\d]+)/$', ArticleDetail.as_view(), name='article_detail'),
    )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add another view that gathers the info and redirects:

```
class ArticleDetailRedirect(RedirectView):

    def get_redirect_url(self, pk):
        article = Article.objects.get(pk=pk)
        slug = article.slug
        return reverse('article_details', args=(pk, slug))
```

Then wire it up in your `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'all$', ArticleList.as_view(), name='blog_all'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ArticleDetailRedirect.as_view(), name='article_redirect'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w\d]+)/$', ArticleDetail.as_view(), name='article_detail'),
    )
```

Comment: spent whole day but finally this answer will let me sleep. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

In case someone comes across this. I wanted to simply redirect and pass in the pk as a keyword argument. Say we have an `Article` model

```
# views.py
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def article_create(request):
    article_form = ArticleForm(request.POST)
    if article_form.is_valid():
        article = article_form.save()
        return redirect("articleDetail", pk=article.id)

# urls.py
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('article/create', views.article_create, name="articleCreate")
    path('article/<int:pk>', views.article_detail, name="articleDetail")
]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is **actually** a redirection, for SEO purpose. You need to create a view, based on `RedirectView` and redirect the user to the page with the slug:

```
class ArticleRedirectView(RedirectView):
    """ Will make a HTTP 301 redirection from blog/1/ to blog/1/slug_of_article """
    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=pk)
        return reverse('article_detail', args=(pk, slug))


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'all$', ArticleList.as_view(), name='blog_all'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ArticleRedirectView.as_view()),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w\d]+)/$', ArticleDetail.as_view(), name='article_detail'),
)
```