# .NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'author-detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['catalog/author/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']

Tags: python, django

Many people have already asked similar questions to this, but I still cannot figure out the solution unfortunately. I am doing a Django tutorial from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Tutorial_local_library_website . I compared my code with theirs on GitHub but I do not see any difference. The current state of my code is here https://github.com/diveki/webdev/tree/master/django_projects/locallibrary it works well except for showing the details of the Author model.

The error message I get is: `django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'author-detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['catalog/author/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']` .

The full error that django gives when I click on the Author list items:

```
NoReverseMatch at /catalog/author/1
Reverse for 'author-detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['catalog/author/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/author/1
Django Version: 3.0.4
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'author-detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['catalog/author/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']
Exception Location: C:\Users\divekizs\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 677
Python Executable:  C:\Users\divekizs\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\django\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.3
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\divekizs\\Python\\Scripts\\WebDev\\django_projects\\locallibrary',
 'C:\\Users\\divekizs\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\envs\\django\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\divekizs\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\envs\\django\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\divekizs\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\envs\\django\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\divekizs\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\envs\\django',
 'C:\\Users\\divekizs\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\envs\\django\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\divekizs\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\envs\\django\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\divekizs\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\envs\\django\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\divekizs\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\envs\\django\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
Server time:    Wed, 18 Mar 2020 18:34:15 +0100
```

Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/author/1

Django Version: 3.0.4
Python Version: 3.7.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'catalog']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template C:\Users\divekizs\Python\Scripts\WebDev\django_projects\locallibrary\catalog\templates\base_generic.html, error at line 6
   Reverse for 'author-detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['catalog/author/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']
   1 : <!DOCTYPE html>
   2 : <html lang="en">
   3 : <head>
   4 :   {% block title %}<title>Local Library</title>{% endblock %}
   5 :   <meta charset="utf-8">
   6 :   <meta name="viewport" co ntent="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" >
   7 :   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
   8 :   <!-- Add additional CSS in static file -->
   9 :   {% load static %}
   10 :   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
   11 : </head>
   12 : <body>
   13 :   <div class="container-fluid">
   14 :     <div class="row">
   15 :       <div class="col-sm-2">
   16 :       {% block sidebar %}


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\divekizs\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\divekizs\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 145, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\divekizs\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 143, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "C:\Users\divekizs\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "C:\Users\divekizs\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "C:\Users\divekizs\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\divekizs\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\divekizs\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\divekizs\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\divekizs\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\divekizs\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\divekizs\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\divekizs\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\divekizs\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\divekizs\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\divekizs\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\divekizs\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\divekizs\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 443, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "C:\Users\divekizs\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 87, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\divekizs\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 677, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /catalog/author/1
Exception Value: Reverse for 'author-detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['catalog/author/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']
```

I do not copy here all the code I wrote for this (unless you need it), but here is my `models.py`, `urls.py` from `catalog`, the relevant code from `views.py` and the templates:

Part of my `catalog/models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse # Used to generate URLs by reversing the URL patterns
import uuid # Required for unique book instances

class Author(models.Model):
    """Model representing an author."""
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_of_death = models.DateField('died', null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['last_name', 'first_name']

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Returns the url to access a particular author instance."""
        return reverse('author-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
        return '{0}, {1}'.format(self.last_name, self.first_name)
```

`catalog/urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('books/', views.BookListView.as_view(), name='books'),
    path('book/<int:pk>', views.BookDetailView.as_view(), name='book-detail'),
    path('authors/', views.AuthorListView.as_view(), name='authors'),
    path('author/<int:pk>',
         views.AuthorDetailView.as_view(), name='author-detail'),
]
```

Complete `catalog/views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from catalog.models import Book, Author, BookInstance, Genre
from django.views import generic

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    num_books = Book.objects.all().count()
    num_instances = BookInstance.objects.all().count()

    #Available Books
    num_instances_available = BookInstance.objects.filter(status__exact='a').count()
    num_authors = Author.objects.count()
    biography_num = Book.objects.filter(genre__name__icontains='horror').count()

    context = {
        'filtered': biography_num,
        'title': 'Changed from index view',
        'num_books': num_books,
        'num_instances': num_instances,
        'num_instances_available': num_instances_available,
        'num_authors': num_authors,
    }

    return render(request, 'index.html', context=context)

class BookListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Book
    paginate_by = 5
    # context_object_name = 'book_list'
    # queryset = Book.objects.filter(title__icontains='zsolt')[:5]
   # 


class BookDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Book
    # context_object_name = 'details'
    # template_name = 'catalog/book_detail.html'


class AuthorListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Author
    paginate_by = 5


class AuthorDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Author
```

And finally here are the templates:

`catalog/templates/base_generic.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  {% block title %}<title>Local Library</title>{% endblock %}
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Add additional CSS in static file -->
  {% load static %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
      {% block sidebar %}
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
          <li><a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'books' %}">All books</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'authors' %}">All authors</a></li>
        </ul>
     {% endblock %}
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10 ">{% block content %}{% endblock %}
        {% block pagination %}
        {% if is_paginated %}
          <div class="pagination">
            <span class="page-links">
              {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                <a href="{{ request.path }}?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
              {% endif %}
              <span class="page-current">
                Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
              </span>
              {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                <a href="{{ request.path }}?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }} ">next</a>
              {% endif %}
            </span>
          </div>
        {% endif %}
      {% endblock %}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

`catalog/templates/catalog/book_details.html`:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Title: {{ book.title }}</h1>

  <p><strong>Author:</strong> <a href="{% url 'author-detail' book.author.pk %}">{{ book.author }}</a></p> <!-- author detail link not yet defined -->
  <p><strong>Summary:</strong> {{ book.summary }}</p>
  <p><strong>ISBN:</strong> {{ book.isbn }}</p> 
  <p><strong>Language:</strong> {{ book.language }}</p>  
  <p><strong>Genre:</strong> {{ book.genre.all|join:", " }}</p>   
 
  <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-top:20px">
    <h4>Copies</h4>

    {% for copy in book.bookinstance_set.all %}
      <hr>
      <p class="{% if copy.status == 'a' %}text-success{% elif copy.status == 'm' %}text-danger{% else %}text-warning{% endif %}">
        {{ copy.get_status_display }}
      </p>
      {% if copy.status != 'a' %}
        <p><strong>Due to be returned:</strong> {{ copy.due_back }}</p>
      {% endif %}
      <p><strong>Imprint:</strong> {{ copy.imprint }}</p>
      <p class="text-muted"><strong>Id:</strong> {{ copy.id }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

`catalog/templates/catalog/book_list.html`:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Book List</h1>
  {% if book_list %}
  <ul>
    {% for book in book_list %}
      <li>
        <a href="{{ book.get_absolute_url }}">{{ book.title }}</a> ({{ book.author }}) {{ book.get_absolute_url }}
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
  {% else %}
    <p>There are no books in the library.</p>
  {% endif %}       
{% endblock %}
```

`catalog/templates/catalog/author_list.html`:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}

<h1>Author List</h1>

{% if author_list %}
  <ul>

  {% for author in author_list %}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ author.get_absolute_url }}">
      {{ author }} ({{author.date_of_birth}} - {% if author.date_of_death %}{{author.date_of_death}}{% endif %})
      </a>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}

 </ul>
{% else %}
  <p>There are no authors available.</p>
{% endif %}
        
        
        
{% endblock %}
```

`catalog/templates/catalog/author_detail.html`:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
hello
{% endblock %}
```

The problem is that `author_detail.html` does not show up because django cannot reverse the `'author-detail'` name. I know that the `{{ author.get_absolute_url }} gives the right url back. I did everything in the same way for the Book model and the` book_list.html`and`book_detail.html` works fine.

Could you please help me resolve the issue?

Comment: Your `get_absolute_url` method looks OK to me. You haven't shown the full error so it's not clear where it's coming from, but I think it might be coming from somewhere else.

Comment: In your GitHub repo, this line would give that error if `details.author.pk` didn't give the `pk`. I think that should be `{% url 'author-detail' author.pk %}`, or if you uncomment out `context_object_name = 'details'` in the view, use `{% url 'author-detail' details.pk %}` (personally I prefer `author.pk`).

Comment: Determine what line is causing the error, see what is being passed in for the args to the url. Then determine why that value is an empty string rather than a valid value.

Comment: @Alasdair, I tried your suggestion, but then by clicking on the books I got an error, basically, it needs the `details.author.pk` .

Comment: Interestingly I do exactly the same thing for the book_list.html and book_detail.html, and the views are basically copy paste, but for the authors it throws error, while for the book it does not.

Comment: It's hard to answer when you don't post your actual code in the question. The traceback shows the error comes from the template for your author details page, but `{% block content %}
hello
{% endblock %}
` would not give that error. The tag `{% url 'author-detail' details.author.pk %}` works in the book detail view because the book has an author field. As I said before, `details.author.pk` doesn't make sense for the author detail view, it should be `details.pk` or `author.pk`.

Comment: I think that using `context_object_name = 'details'` has made your code more confusing here. If you copied `{% url 'author-detail' book.author.pk %}` to the author detail page, it would be easier to spot that `book` is not set in the view.

Comment: @Alasdair, do you think we could chat? or if you want I can post any code here that you tell me. By the way, even if I removed the `context_object_name = 'details'` and turned back to the `book` notation and it  did not work if I wrote only `author.pk` .

Comment: But actually, I don't have to go to the `book_detail.html`, I get the inserted error even if I go from the `author_list.html`

Comment: The error is coming from the author details view, if you can’t get it to work you need to [edit] your question to include the current view, template and traceback.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209871/discussion-between-zsolt-diveki-and-alasdair).

Comment: `<!--` comments are ignored by the browser, but Django renders the entire template. The traceback clearly shows the issue is in the author details template.

Comment: Huh, interesting, you were right. Removing the comments in the author_detail.html it suddenly worked. Sorry for being so difficult to understand, but I would not think about that ever.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `get_absolute_url` is not returning the correct value

`def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Returns the url to access a particular author instance."""
        return reverse('author-detail', args=[str(self.id)])`

I would try something more along the lines of

`def get_absolute_url(self, pk):
    author = Author.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return reverse('author-detail', args=pk`)

[how to redirect a url with pk to url with pk and slug in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23817396/how-to-redirect-a-url-with-pk-to-url-with-pk-and-slug-in-django)

Comment: Hi, I tried your `return reverse('author-detail', int=self.id)` line, but then even my author list view did not work. It gave the following error:
```
TypeError at /catalog/authors/
reverse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'int'
```

Comment: The problem isn’t coming from `get_absolute_url`. In `reverse`, args should be a list so `reverse('author-detail', args=pk)` isn’t going to work.